# Can typescript infer a function's response type based on parameter values?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have an API with that takes a request object to get a list of records. If `inlineCount` is set on the request object, the API returns `{ results: T[], inlineCount: number }`. Otherwise, `T[]` is returned.

This looks something like:

```js
interface inlineCountResult<T> {
    results: T[];
    inlineCount: number;
}

interface Options {
  inlineCount?: boolean;
}

async getApiResponse<T>(options: Options): T[] | inlineCountResult<T> {
  return this.http.get(options);
}

async getClients(options: Options) {
  return this.getApiResponse<model.Client>(options);
}
```

Here's what I'm hoping to have happen:

```js
let responseAsArray: model.Client[] = getClients();
let responseWithCount: inlineCountResult<model.Client> = getClients({ inlineCount: true });
```

However, the type of both calls is `model.Client[] | inlineCountResult<model.Client>` which makes my code require unnecessary type castings to work properly. I understand I can do the following, but I'd like to avoid the `as` casting:

```js
const clients: Client[] = await (getClients(clientQueryOptions) as Promise<Client[]>);
```

One idea I had is to write a function that will return one of the return types as one of the args, but I'd like to get by without the extra arg being required.

*Partial solution:*

```js
//
// 2 "normalize" functions each with a single return type
//
export function normalizeArray<T>(result: T[] | inlineCountResult<T>): T[] {
    return Array.isArray(result) ? result : result.results;
}

export function normalizeInlineCount = function normalizeInlineCount<T>(result: T[] | inlineCountResult<T>) {
    return Array.isArray(result) ? new inlineCountResult<T>(result, result.length) : result.inlineCount ? result : new inlineCountResult<T>([], 0);
}

//
// Types for request
//
export interface ExecuteQueryRequest {
    inlineCount?: boolean;
}
export type QueryResponseNormalizer<T, TResponse> = (response: (T[] | inlineCountResult<T>)) => TResponse;

//
// Query method to handle
//
function executeQuery<T, TResponse>(request: ExecuteQueryRequest, normalizeResults: QueryResponseNormalizer<T, TResponse>): TResponse {
    const items: T[] = []; // eg call HTTP service

    return normalizeResults(items);
}

// One API for both scenarios
function getClients<TResponse>(request: ExecuteQueryRequest, normalizeResults: QueryResponseNormalizer<model.Client, TResponse>) {
    let response = executeQuery(request as ExecuteQueryRequest, normalizeResults);
    return response;
}

//
// Example calls
//
let responseA: inlineCountResult<model.Client> = getClients({ inlineCount: true }, normalizeInlineCount);
let responseB: model.Client[] = getClients({}, normalizeArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional types it's possible to have the result type depend on the presence of `inlineCount` in the parameter, and also infer the type of the result array from the normalize function. Disregarding the promises for simplicity, you can define these helper types:

```ts
interface InlineCountResult<T> {
  results: T[]
  inlineCount: number
}

interface InlineCountOption {
  inlineCount: boolean
}

type PlainNormalizer<T> = (res: T[]) => T[]

type InlineCountNormalizer<T> = (res: InlineCountResult<T>) => InlineCountResult<T>

type Normalizer<O, T> =
  O extends InlineCountOption ? InlineCountNormalizer<T> : PlainNormalizer<T>

type Result<O, T> = O extends InlineCountOption ? InlineCountResult<T> : T[]
```

and type `getClients` like this:

```ts
function getClients<O, T>(options: O, normalizer: Normalizer<O, T>): Result<O, T> {
  return {} as any
}
```

If you now define two dummy normalizers like these

```ts
const normalizeInlineCount: InlineCountNormalizer<number> = {} as any
const normalizeArray: PlainNormalizer<string> = {} as any
```

the types of the responses will be inferred correctly and incorrectly-typed normalizers will yield type errors:

```ts
const responseA = getClients({ inlineCount: true }, normalizeInlineCount)
const responseB = getClients({}, normalizeArray)
const responseC = getClients({ inlineCount: true }, normalizeArray) // type error
const responseD = getClients({}, normalizeInlineCount) // type error
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgDaggYQPYCu4AShAM4EZgA8AKgHzIDeAUMslOZWGQFzK0A2gF02yUFhC5C4fiAIBbAEbQWAXxYtQkWIhTpJ0omADyABzDA8IZmInZ8x-krx4MEOCHWawATzMoAAoYcKAAcnhQCnBYAF7QdIwAvMgAFJx8AiIAlMhJjEKiLH4BaJgOMmARUTHA8VCJeWkZ-AYVxqQUVIm5+WWGjiRc3Qw+-ijV0XEJJgA0AsliJsgQAB6QIAAmZP3t4OaW1sgA-LtSg1WRU3UJDMj8waEgk7X1iWOlndzUcwtNy2sNtszkZ9hYrDZTm1zpUviNGPxCshNDAiAhDjYAOYQMA4LAQcBkH7zBipPDg6yZX4gK6vaD8F7TBq-BjZfhwmgsxisdicMAEKA2JhqZBwHaeXzeFgISlgZA0mrTaGgsCtcow4yMm4NeTKaDJZgisWikCSmUgMhyhXXeIAQSgUDgvgeIXCtKZ1EtUFAmINwtF4tNmnNlo45DMlIgtqa2Nx+MJqSY4nVKv4YCgBBQanm1rpyou2WlsrDZAjFogACEYzi8cACTxE9n5e6bvbHb5CyG5Rky2RcNW43WE0n7BrZMh05nkE3c9M207cgB6RcT8YrB2RIsW7vhyMAEQHtfrZEbOZb8XzlSXK5KKGgUE3LCAA)

You'll need to tweak it a bit to account for the promises, and maybe other option properties besides `inlineCount`, but this should give you a rough idea of a solution.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! The normalize function was an example to try to get me to my ideal, but you helped me reach a good solution. I'll post my own solution separately.

Answer (score 0):

Oblosys's answer helped me get to a solution that allows my ideal/simple API surface without needing any extra args/types in my callers other than 2 distinct `Options` vs `InlineCountOptions` types with and without the `inlineCount` bool:

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTBQIAgEQUwMwJYDsYRkgLgrMDO4wkBDAWzwAciBjVEgewBMYAbCAb1AjQA9y6AnDBGQYY-ONVQBhZgnRCOXLlVnyAcqRgAuCLgz9kAcwDcnCAF9QlggQgAlGAEcArngzB+FOklyoRYiRp8EFB-cUkIAHlyLG9cdjNEZlF+AH4dIiQAT1MuXAEMdN19I1NrMMDUAEkkWRQpOmdMaNikHlEkBniWhDiErmQ6mAamjB0AIzo6ZhhMq1BQzACImqGRzAdcZ2SAHgAVAD5+iE8t5NwdPYBtAF0zQeRhxswdJGcScbF50Aws8lQet4dpF2ugulEYr0fEcALxRUGdeKrR7rDCAtqpCDI+rPNGQ7wQHTo3CmOBNKitCAuMRZYnAg4ACjo+J8RIAlESWfTjp4MM5+G1ma14kQRdkygsQpAAOLoMQIKgQACCAAUqhAqERmDN+DZfv97HhthhgQAaCCHCBwkEwbgdcHYp6jdEQTGO1GbY37I6XW4QUCirJIRVk4OUgAW2CV5AQZotjP5zB0egMSEM5qFUNwRUiHIgKv4dBICF8O09u0i5sOR0UEBmQgYRAwRB0TQA1kg6AB3Npw27GCCQW0LLi8-ltRvNiCiw1nE2V+MSmyQADK-yoCEQIYEaGo4bQmGwWWA9CYzBsoYpUIghhgGBkckwuHpTJZ2fZOgLRZLMDLRor5qniwAB0D7yAcNZmGOAoQJGGDRggDIAOS3veqhPkhGZvmyS5SsAyq4EGIbkpSGB0CcTTToRwYnE4rh6MEYCBjRl6Ut4NTYAybLHCEXCQEq-D8EQWS0dSehmLxxx8fhQHMKB6EYLcZjKHEQgqI+GDxHCRBdkQ2A3neYFPlxuRKFQqkagpGhkFplkabgwEkEQ5AMtwVpHNwwHqeomg4SOSiQO6uLliasnyRpBzKRqFmnHwPioNpun6ahRmaQybDCLUKK4jo+iuBYflKNFPhCA8OKjFatG4HFvjAWVTqYKZ1hcLWKklXZ8gAIquPwtJvpV1K9cS6XmH5UWQGFqVKUV5ntd5T6VTpelCClCm4Ay80YN1NLEmNM0WZt1l4JVm0OU5LluTCHleVZvlNf5kmBVlKDRRVnhiRgElgC1UWzXoHWYNtQ39XCg19cK6WZWsOUQHlqCjaY434UFowhTsk0KZF+1zWtmw1Ql05JSthlrRtClA+DWZ7WZFlvCQqW2adeNxDAdXPQ1GCmW1-2nSduNePFwGnMaJK-Qdt02Xz9mOc5rnuRAnmHXdZiWOYQA)

```js
// model.Client[]
const clients = await getClients();
// or
const clients2 = await getClients({ sort: "clientName" });

// InlineCountResult<model.Client>
const response = await getClients({ inlineCount: true });
```

---

## Full Solution

### Setup

Define entities for data coming from the API

```js
namespace model {
  export interface Client {
    clientName: string;
  }
}
```

Define Request/response interfaces

```js
interface Options {
  filter?: any;
  skip?: number;
  page?: number;
  sort?: string;
}

interface InlineCountOption extends Options {
  inlineCount: boolean
}

interface InlineCountResult<T> {
  results: T[]
  inlineCount: number
}

type Option<O extends Options> = O extends InlineCountOption ? InlineCountOption : Options;
function queryOptions<O>(options: O): Option<O> {
  return options as any;
}
```

### Methods

Generic API caller, eg `fetch`

```js
type Result<O, T> = O extends InlineCountOption ? InlineCountResult<T> : T[] 
async function hitApi<O, T>(url: string, options: O): Promise<Result<O, T>> {
  let data: unknown = []; // ex

  return data as Result<O, T>;
}
```

Specific for each entity/model

```
function getClients<O>(options: O): Promise<Result<O, model.Client>> {
  return hitApi('getClients', options);
}
```

### Usage

Array request

```js
const clientQueryOptions = queryOptions({});

// model.Client[]
const clients = await getClients(clientQueryOptions);

const clientNames = clients.map(x => x.clientName);
```

Inline count request

```js
const clientQueryOptions = queryOptions({ inlineCount: true });

// InlineCountResult<model.Client>
const clientsResponse = await getClients(clientQueryOptions);

const numClients = clientsResponse.inlineCount;
const clients = clientsResponse.results;
const clientNames = clients.map(x => x.clientName);
```